# RxJs staircase when chaining Observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Before I was using Promise with async/await syntax in Typescript looking as following

```
const fooData = await AsyncFooData();
const barData = await AsyncBarData();

... do something with fooData and barData
```

If I do it with RxJs `Observable<T>` it becomes something like this for me

```
AsyncFooData().subscribe(fooData => {
   AsyncBarData().subscribe(barData => {
      ... do something with fooData and barData
   })
})
```

Is there some better way to do this? Because it becomes fast not readable, ala Staircase, if I would have more AsyncData I need to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't quite be able to do what you've done with `async`/`await` since you still have to have the `.subscribe` callback and there is the potential for multiple properties to be emitted. You should *never* nest `.subscribe` calls. Typically you will use a higher order Observable operator such as `mergeMap`, or an Observable creator that syncs the emission of multiple Observables together such as `combineLatest`:

```
combineLatest(AsyncFooData(), AsyncBarData()).subscribe([fooData, barData] => {

});
```

The exact function you need depends on your own needs as well as how `foo` and `bar` emit:

- `combineLatest` - Emits every time any source emits (**note:** does not start emitting until all sources have emitted once).
- `zip` - Synchronizes emissions, e.g. emits once each Observable has emitted once, then twice, etc.
- `forkJoin` - Emits when all source observables have completed
- `merge` - Emits whenever any source emits. It does not combine outputs like the others above.

There are more available: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/

Comment: thanks for the tip, I ended up using operators as you suggested. became a little bit better I think :)

Comment: In your case @starcorn, since your functions seemed to be promises, use forkJoin. Promises always complete.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to find a nice way to chain multiple async operations in a 'cleaner' way. This is what I do:

- i used `from()` as I assumed `AsyncFooData` returns a promise. If it returns Observable, just remove the `from()`.
- avoid multiple subscriptions (usually, less frequent than we think).
- use `pipe()` to chain appropriate operators, as many as you need in a pretty flat way.
- `subscribe()` is called when all the operations are done.
- Style A pass along result from foo all the way to subscribe's next function.
- Style B only works with the last async operation's result.

Note: These examples are written to share concept/approach, without IDE syntax check. The concept should work but apology if there are syntax errors.

```
// A: if you need both foo and bar
from(AsyncFooData()).pipe(
  concatMap(foo => AsyncBarData().pipe(
    map(bar => ({foo, bar})
  )),
  tap(val => console.log(val), // chain more operators here...
).subscribe(({foo, bar}) => {
  // do stuff with foo and bar
})

// B: if foo is only used to get bar (i.e. no need to pass it along)
from(AsyncFooData()).pipe(
  concatMap(foo => AsyncBarData(foo)), // assume foo is only used to get bar
  tap(val => console.log(val), // chain more operators here...
).subscribe(bar => {
  // do stuff with bar
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I solved it using operators as your suggested tip. It still became kinda long. But I'm not using `subscribe` nor does it look like a staircase anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You may `zip` and get `fooData` and `barData` and do whatever you want to do.

```
zip(AsyncFooData(), AsyncBarData()).subscribe([fooData, barData]) => {})
```

Here `zip` is taken as an example. You may use other operators such as `combineLatest` according to your needs.

I refrain from explaining the differences between `zip` and `combineLatest` and other operators here because doing so may clutter this answer. Instead I point the following resources, there things are clearly explained with diagrams and examples:

(1) [Official doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#categories-of-operators)

(2) [Marble diagrams](http://rxmarbles.com/)