# How to pass action data downstream a pipeable operator stream in rxjs?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a situation where I want to access action payload in a third level operation. 
I was able to such thing in lettable operators but how can I do the same with pipeable operator?

this my code,

```
 @Effect()
  onTrySignin = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGNIN),
    map((action: AuthActions.TrySignin) => {
      return action.payload;
    }),
    switchMap(action => {
      return this.httpService
        .postRequest('UserAccounts/Login', action.credentials);
    }), catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      return Observable.of(new AuthActions.FailedAuth(error));
    }),
    mergeMap((response: any) => {
      // how to access action payload here?
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` to pass data along an observable chain like this:

```
// both foo and bar will be available on next()
from(AsyncFooData()).pipe(
  concatMap(foo => AsyncBarData().pipe(
    map(bar => ({foo, bar})
  )),
  tap(val => console.log(val), // chain more operators here...
).subscribe(({foo, bar}) => {
  // do stuff with foo and bar
})
```

FWIW, I took this answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065887/rxjs-staircase-when-chaining-observable/51066290#51066290) where I posted a somewhat similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok, its a `pipe` inside a `pipe`

```
 @Effect()
  onTrySignin = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGNIN),
    map((action: AuthActions.TrySignin) => {
      return action.payload;
    }),
    switchMap(actionPayload => {
      return this.httpService.postRequest('UserAccounts/Login', actionPayload.credentials).pipe(
        mergeMap((response: HttpResponse<IApiResponder<string>>) => {
          switch (response.status) {
            case 200:
              if (actionPayload.returnUrl) {
                this.router.navigate([actionPayload.returnUrl]);
              } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/dbapp']);
              }
              return Observable.concat(
                Observable.of(new AuthActions.GenerateAntiforgeryToken()),
                Observable.of(new AuthActions.Signin(this.authService.getUserData())),
              );
          }
        }),
        catchError(e => {
          return Observable.of(new AuthActions.FailedAuth(e));
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
```

Comment: I was re-reading your question and about to suggest you `pipe` from `postRequest` instead so that you have access to `action`. Looks like you're already doing that. Surprised you marked my answer as correct since it did not solve your problem... but cheers anyway! :-)

Comment: @kctang, Your answer lead me to chain pipes which is the core solution of my question, `AsyncFooData` and piping `AsyncBarData`,,, Thanks :)